# How do I make the 'next' arrow align with the rightmost edge of the red box it is in?

Tags: css

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items: center;
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
}
.title{
  font-size:55px;
  letter-spacing:5px;
  width:100%;
  background:yellow;
  flex-basis:30px;
  flex-grow:2.5;
  
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.box{
  width:85vw;
  background:green;
  flex-basis:120px;
  flex-grow:4;
  border-radius:10px;
}

.buttons{
  width:100%;
  background:red;
  flex-basis:30px;
  flex-grow:.5;
  font-size:35px;
  width:85vw;
 
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  
  }
.button{
  background:blue;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:1px;
  height:40px;
  width:40px;
  
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    <div>
    Random Quote Generator
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    This is Where Author and Quote go.
  </div>
  <p class="blank"></p>
  <div class="buttons">
    <a class="button"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>       </a>
    <a class='button'><i class="fa fa-tumblr"></i></a>
    <a class='button' id='arrow'><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The twitter and tumblr buttons can stay to the left, but the arrow go to the right. I don't how to do that.

I saw in a similar project, that the author uses a ID like id="arrow" for the  tag that contains the arrow. And do &#arrow{flow:right;}. Tried it but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `margin-left: auto` on `#arrow`. That will cause the left margin to consume the available space between it and it's sibling to the left.

```css
#arrow {
  margin-left: auto;
}

*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items: center;
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
}
.title{
  font-size:55px;
  letter-spacing:5px;
  width:100%;
  background:yellow;
  flex-basis:30px;
  flex-grow:2.5;
  
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.box{
  width:85vw;
  background:green;
  flex-basis:120px;
  flex-grow:4;
  border-radius:10px;
}

.buttons{
  width:100%;
  background:red;
  flex-basis:30px;
  flex-grow:.5;
  font-size:35px;
  width:85vw;
 
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  
  }
.button{
  background:blue;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:1px;
  height:40px;
  width:40px;
  
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    <div>
    Random Quote Generator
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    This is Where Author and Quote go.
  </div>
  <p class="blank"></p>
  <div class="buttons">
    <a class="button"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>       </a>
    <a class='button'><i class="fa fa-tumblr"></i></a>
    <a class='button' id='arrow'><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you do?

Comment: @user132522 _"Used `margin-left: auto` on `#arrow`. That will cause the left margin to consume the available space between it and it's sibling to the left."_

Comment: How come do can do it with just # I saw some people use &#?

Comment: @user132522 I have no idea. do you have a link/example? it could be SCSS/SASS nesting?

Comment: @user132522 that's sass/scss.

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items: center;
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
}
.title{
  font-size:55px;
  letter-spacing:5px;
  width:100%;
  background:yellow;
  flex-basis:30px;
  flex-grow:2.5;
  
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.box{
  width:85vw;
  background:green;
  flex-basis:120px;
  flex-grow:4;
  border-radius:10px;
}

.buttons{
  width:100%;
  background:red;
  flex-basis:30px;
  flex-grow:.5;
  font-size:35px;
  width:85vw;
 
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  
  }
.button{
  background:blue;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:1px;
  height:40px;
  width:40px;
  
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

/* 
Auto margins on flex items have similar effect like auto margins on 
block elements. Adding a margin-left of auto to arrow will make it flow 
to right. 
*/
#arrow {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    <div>
    Random Quote Generator
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    This is Where Author and Quote go.
  </div>
  <p class="blank"></p>
  <div class="buttons">
    <a class="button"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>       </a>
    <a class='button'><i class="fa fa-tumblr"></i></a>
    <a class='button' id='arrow'><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```